Get intellisense completed item in YoCode VS Code extension
I want a console log to show the item that was provided for intellisense autocompletion upon clicking 'Enter'.
This is for custom languages and I just need a way to determine if something was chosen and what type of autocompletion was done.
This is not for my own intellisense autocompletion, but rather for pre-existing ones.
vscode.languages.getCompletionItems 

But it seems it's more for my own custom made items rather than existing ones.
This should work for any language and not only JavaScript. I have been searching within the classes documentation and tried my best to find something relevant to fail.
